# Help Us Test The iOS Beta Version

Tags: discussion, ios-app

We are getting ready to release the next Appstore update for the Stack Exchange iOS app – *version 1.0.2*.

This update will contain the following new features:

- **Achievements Page.** All your upvotes and badges in a single place.
- **Realtime Notifications.** The app will notify users whenever any of the following information changes serverside:

  - Question details (votes, edits, and new answers)
  - Newest and active Question Listings (on certain sites)
- **Favorite Questions** cached for your offline viewing pleasure

We will continue to use our Beta channel testing before we submit an update. (Currently at version 1.0.1.81+). If you don't have access to it, you can [sign up here](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform).

As always, we welcome your feedback.

Comment: The realtime notifications thing has been working well, but one request: could you change the color of the update banner to be different from the "request failed" errors? And new comments would be a nice addition to the system too

Comment: Is there a way to set whether or not to cache favorites? Some people have hundreds of favorites but are pressed for space on their phones. That said I had no idea it was caching it. Brilliant!

Comment: I was part of the Alpha test run, and kept the Alpha version installed, adding the app store version. However, it never got updated after installing the app store release. I am at 1.0.0.67. Anything I need to do to upgrade to the beta?

Comment: @mhlester I'm currently working on caching just 1) you 10 most recently favorited questions and 2) favorite questions you've visited on device.  The implementation in the beta channel a naive approach.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You should be getting update notifications again in the alpha app.  They were broken for a while.  If not, you can download from the link in the original email.

Comment: @BrianNickel: Found the email, downloading now!

Comment: I'm stuck in an infinite loop with 1.0.1.83 - keeps saying it's not supported and I need to update, so I do; goto 1. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: @AaronBertrand should be fixed now. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234371/wrong-alpha-channel-version/234397#234397