# iOS Achievements view doesn't roll over on UTC days properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, achievements-dialog

In the achievements dropdown on the desktop site, *Today* becomes *Yesterday* at 00:00 UTC:

> [image: desktop yesterday]

But in the iOS app, *Today* becomes *Yesterday* at local midnight, rather than local 5:00 PM Pacific:

> [image: ios today]

Both screenshots taken at the same time, but one says *Today* and the other says *Yesterday*. In the app new achievements will continue to appear under the same *Today* header until midnight, while on the desktop the old achievements are moved to *Yesterday* and a new *Today* header created.

<sup><sup>[Related discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234296/help-us-test-the-ios-beta-version?noredirect=1#comment770310_234296)</sup></sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in **beta version 1.0.1.82**.

I *thought* I had been using the UTC dates, but there was a missing step that prevented me from doing so.