# Wrong alpha channel version

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The alpha channel launch page says there is version 1.0.1.84 to install but actually installs 1.0.1.83 resulting in the app asking to update again.

Can't use alpha app as result.

Comment: I figured out how to use the app. When it tells you to update, press the `update now` button. It takes you to the website, at which point switch back to the app. It won't ask you again.

Comment: But yeah, broken update nonetheless

Comment: @mhlester oh, I thought it's not possible to get rid of the dialog or it will just pop up again. Thanks!

Comment: Crashes after a couple of minutes too if you use that workaround.

Comment: The crash seems to happen when you try and view a question (as opposed to some length of time). I also don't think it has to do with using a *workaround* since that has worked in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just released version 1.0.1.85. This will fix the issue, though you will definitely have to upgrade to this version ;-)

Looks like we had a mixup in the automated version increment when we were developing and building the code in this latest cycle.