# Problems updating iOS app to 1.0.1.84

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm running 1.0.1.83 and keep getting messages to update. Clicking the update link takes me to the App Store, from where I can download the new app, but that still seems to have the version 1.0.1.83 tag, rather than 1.0.1.84. So, I seem to be locked in an update loop rather than being able to use the app. Hopefully this is just affecting me rather than all alpha-testers of the app?

Comment: [It's not just you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234371/wrong-alpha-channel-version)

Comment: And me too, sadly.